# ¿Como abrir un enlace externo en otra pestaña en blogger?

Tags: blogger

Resulta que tengo una pagina en blogger sobre mi grupo escolar y tengo una sección de paginas que se muestra de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que la pagina llamada "Sistema Integral de Información (SII)" y la del "Ingles" que son enlaces externos, que me los abra en una nueva pestaña, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Les dejo el codigo del gadget de "Páginas":

```html
<b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' title='Páginas' type='PageList'>
          <b:widget-settings>
            <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'><![CDATA[{'home': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/', 'title': 'Página principal', 'position': 0}, '5360924209717943521': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/graficacion.html', 'title': 'Graficación', 'position': 1}, '6751111000090202277': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/fundamentos-de-telecomunicaciones.html', 'title': 'Fundamentos de Telecomunicaciones', 'position': 2}, '3802776948014366895': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/sistemas-operativos.html', 'title': 'Sistemas Operativos', 'position': 3}, '2186380374492364627': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/taller-de-base-de-datos.html', 'title': 'Taller de Base de Datos', 'position': 4}, '3182055506244506366': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/fundamentos-de-ingenieria-de-software.html', 'title': 'Fundamentos de Ingeniería de Software', 'position': 5}, '804256781924013445': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/arquitectura-de-computadoras.html', 'title': 'Arquitectura de Computadoras', 'position': 6}, 'link0': {'href': 'http://sii.itsguasave.edu.mx/', 'title': 'Sistema Integral de Información (SII)', 'position': 7}, 'link1': {'href': 'http://www.itsguasave.edu.mx/english', 'title': 'Inglés', 'position': 8}, '5933906471858052628': {'href': 'https://www.itsg-isc-501.tk/p/contacto.html', 'title': 'Contacto', 'position': 9}}]]></b:widget-setting>
            <b:widget-setting name='homeTitle'>Página principal</b:widget-setting>
          </b:widget-settings>
          <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'><h2><data:title/></h2></b:if>
  <div class='widget-content'>
    <b:if cond='data:mobile'>
      <select expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_select&quot;'>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <option expr:value='data:link.href'>
            <b:attr cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected' value='selected'/>
            <data:link.title/>
          </option>
        </b:loop>
      </select>
      <span class='pagelist-arrow'>&amp;#9660;</span>
    <b:else/>
      <ul>
        <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
          <li>
            <b:class cond='data:link.isCurrentPage' name='selected'/>
            <a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a>
          </li>
        </b:loop>
      </ul>
    </b:if>
    <b:include name='quickedit'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
        </b:widget>
      </b:section>
      <b:section class='tabs' id='crosscol-overflow' name='Cross-Column 2' showaddelement='no'/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='tabs-cap-bottom cap-bottom'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class='main-outer'>
    <div class='main-cap-top cap-top'>
      <div class='cap-left'/>
      <div class='cap-right'/>
    </div>

    <div class='fauxborder-left main-fauxborder-left'>
    <div class='fauxborder-right main-fauxborder-right'/>
    <div class='region-inner main-inner'>

      <div class='columns fauxcolumns'>

        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-center-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
          <div class='cap-left'/>
          <div class='cap-right'/>
        </div>
        <div class='fauxborder-left'>
        <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='cap-bottom'>
          <div class='cap-left'/>
          <div class='cap-right'/>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-left-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
          <div class='cap-left'/>
          <div class='cap-right'/>
        </div>
        <div class='fauxborder-left'>
        <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='cap-bottom'>
          <div class='cap-left'/>
          <div class='cap-right'/>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class='fauxcolumn-outer fauxcolumn-right-outer'>
        <div class='cap-top'>
          <div class='cap-left'/>
          <div class='cap-right'/>
        </div>
        <div class='fauxborder-left'>
        <div class='fauxborder-right'/>
        <div class='fauxcolumn-inner'>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class='cap-bottom'>
          <div class='cap-left'/>
          <div class='cap-right'/>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!-- corrects IE6 width calculation -->
        <div class='columns-inner'>

        <div class='column-center-outer'>
        <div class='column-center-inner'>
          <b:section class='main' id='main' name='Main' showaddelement='no'>
```

He intentado lo del target="_blank" pero no funciona con esas dos paginas que quiero que se abran en una nueva pestaña.

¿Alguna forma de que funcione lo que quiero hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné

Era abajo de

```html
</li>
        </b:loop>
```

poner esta linea:

```html
<li><a href='http://sii.itsguasave.edu.mx/' target='_blank'>Sistema Integral de Información (SII)</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.itsguasave.edu.mx/english/' target='_blank'>Ingles</a></li>
```